# Aggregation query not returning any value

Tags: sql

I want to see how many stores have not reported any events in my events table.

[image]

I have written this query to do so, but it's not returning the sum

```
SELECT SUM(Site.SiteId)
FROM Site
WHERE Site.SiteId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Site.SiteId From Event)
```

Comment: Your query has to return a row, even if the value is `NULL`.  You might want to include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Site s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Event e
                  WHERE e.SiteId = s.SiteId
                 );
```

If any rows in `Event` have a `NULL` value for `SiteId`, then `NOT IN` matches no rows at all.  For this reason, I *always* recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` with subqueries.

In addition, the sum of an id column doesn't make sense.  I am guessing you want the count.